# Asus RT-AC58U DNS point all .lan domains to local machine

Tags: router, dns, dnsmasq, asuswrt-merlin

I have an Asus RT-AC58U and am setting up a development server on my local network.

I would like to point all .lan domains to this local server via the router as I want to avoid editing host files on machines that are trying to access the dev server.

I have read that is can be done if you flash AsusWRT-Merlin to an Asus router, but my particular router is not supported.

Is there another way I may be able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will put this here in case someone else runs into the same problem.

I found there was no real way of changing the router dns to point all .lan domains to my local dev server, as this particular router is not supported well by open source router software that is often flashed to routers, eg. AsusWRT-Merlin.

Instead I installed dnsmasq on the dev server and told it to point all .lan domains to it's own IP and then passthrough other DNS queries to Google (8.8.8.8).
I then set the router's DNS settings (under the WAN settings) to use this local dev server as it's first DNS, and the google DNS (8.8.8.8) as it's secondary DNS.
This way, when my local dev server is turned on, the router uses it's DNS, when the local dev server is turned off, the router uses the google DNS.

It works well.

Comment: UPDATE... after about a year I removed dnsmasq and instead installed PiHole on my dev server via a docker container and used that as my local DNS, which not only blocks many website ads, but also allows you to set your own dns entries.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone looking for similar solution on the AX58U you can use Merlin to do so, just doesnt work on the AC one - but you could still get openWRT on it(AC58U)

I just found out how to set it up correctly with AsusWRT-Merlin.

https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/wiki/Custom-domains-with-dnsmasq

even without the last bit with those settings and the option to define a Hostname under DHCP-Server setting I got it working.

tried on RT-AX58U with Merlin 384.19

Comment: Different router. [RT-AC58U](https://www.asus.com/Networking-IoT-Servers/WiFi-Routers/ASUS-WiFi-Routers/RT-AC58U/) and [RT-AX58U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RT-AX58U/). RT-AC58U is not supported by WRT-Merlin.

Comment: damm, sorry that was one reason I switched from AC to AX unit - but I did manage to flash openWRT on my AC58U after soldering on the PINS for the serial Connection :-)
which should be supporting dnsmasq too now.